# How combine simple geometric figures in one object?

Tags: c++, winapi

I had draw cylinder by simple geometric figures.
For example:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    hdc=BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
    pen1=CreatePen(PS_SOLID,3,RGB(0,0,0));
    SelectObject(hdc,pen1);
    Arc(hdc,10,10,200,100,40,40,40,40);
    MoveToEx(hdc,10,50,NULL);
    LineTo(hdc,10,200);
    MoveToEx(hdc,199,50,NULL);
    LineTo(hdc,199,200);
    Arc(hdc,10,150,200,250,10,199,200,200);
    DeleteObject(pen1);
    EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
```

How I can combine all figures in one complex object and use it?
Maybe there are some functions that do it or create my own function?

Comment: What do you mean by "use it"?  Move all drawn objects to other coordinates with stretch possibilities?  See "BitBlt", "StretchBlt" functions for starting.

Comment: I mean create more similar objects

Comment: or maybe create rectangle and cut from it some figures using CreateRectRgn,CreateEllipticRgn and then CombineRgn?

Comment: Regions could be a possibility. Keep in mind that you're working with bitmaps, basically. For more complex object handling (e.g: selection, group, ungroup, layering,etc) you should look for a vector-drawing framework, e.g: Cairo. http://cairographics.org/

Comment: Thank you, I try to do something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex objects like this are probably best built with [metafiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (assuming you want to stick with raw GDI).

You start by creating a metafile with [CreateEnhMetafile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which gives you a virtual DC that you can draw in.  You then draw into the DC using GDI calls.  When you're done drawing, call [CloseEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), followed by [GetEnhMetaFileBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144881%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to copy the metafile into your buffer.

To draw the metafile, retrieve the metafile into a buffer, call [SetEnhMetaFileBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the metafile handle, and then call [PlayEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to draw it.  You can set transforms to translate/shear/zoom the metafile.